# Watchkit AppIcon - The app icon set named "AppIcon" did not have any applicable content

Tags: ios, watchkit

There is the Images.xcassets file in my WatchKit App. As soon as I put any icon in that asset build failed with the error message: *"The app icon set named "AppIcon" did not have any applicable content."*

[image]

Answer (score 147, accepted):

This is an easy method to generate your WatchKit icons, which worked well for me:

- Upload a source image to http://makeappicon.com
- Go to Images.xcassets in the WatchKit app
- Right click on the pane which includes AppIcon, select "Import...", and choose the watchkit folder that makeappicon.com generated for you

Comment: I found https://appiconmaker.co better as it doesn't require your email address in a sneaky way after you finished uploading your icon.

Answer (score 33):

Most likely your watchKit app icons are not of the correct size. You need the following sizes

```
    (these are all in pixels)
    48 x 48
    55 x 55
    58 x 58
    80 x 80
    87 x 87
    88 x 88
    172 x 172
    196 x 196
```

Basically all the numbers you see in at bottom under Images.xcassets you need to double them as they need to be retina display.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

**Most likely your watchKit app icons are not of the correct size. You need follow the instructions in above image**

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I generated the images with required dimensions from Sketch. I then dragged and dropped the png files into the spots. No complaints from Xcode. My app doesn't use watch kit.

However build failed with the error message, "The app icon set named “AppIcon” did not have any applicable content". There were also warnings about the wrong dimensions of the image files. Not sure how Sketch did that but I went back and reconfigured export from Sketch, verified the exported dimensions, drag the new files back to the app icon spots in Xcode. This time build was successful.

Morality, if you see this error message, double check your image dimensions.

Comment: For some reason Sketch kept exporting my images off by one or two pixels. Making sure I had the exact dimensions got rid of the error for me.

Answer (score 3):

[image: appicon]

From [human-interface-guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/specifications/).

Answer (score 2):

Lets write it down into lazy mode easy version, all other answers were confusing me the hell out. i hope following help others.

## Step 1: AppIcon was empty

[image]

## Step 2: Want to add icon

so from AppIcon > on row1, col1 on 2x > i drag and dropped, the following invalid image:

[image]

Which had actual size as below:

[image]

## Step 3: when i did build compile, it failed.

[image]
[image]

## Step 4: after searching

i found that for 2x the image size should be 40px by 40px so i modified that image into 40px by 40px from that invalid value.

[image]
[image]

## Step 5: Info.plist added entry as below.

[image]
[image]

This time the build/compile worked and in my iPhone 7 i have the new icon.

Answer (score -2):

## I solved the problem!

originally I only selected Apple Watch checkbox in Xcode 6 and run very well. However, I got the same error in Xcode 7 without modifying anything. My solution is to **select CarPlay checkbox** in addition and put in two square icons with 120px and 180px for CarPlay. Now I can run my watchapp finally.

However, it cannot be accepted for submitting to Apple Store...

[image]