# Error: The app icon set named "AppIcon" did not have any applicable content

Tags: ios, watchkit

I know that there are several questions on StackOverflow with similar content, but it seems that I am still unable to get the solution to this issue.

I have:

1. Made sure my AppIcons are the adequate size
2. Put the images into Images.xcassets

The keyword "AppIcon" does not show up anywhere in my .plist files. I have built cleaned the application and reran the application. I am a bit unsure what is the issue. I get this error when I build this on both Watch + IOS targets for device.

The strange thing is that if I deleted all the image files from xcassets, Xcode compiles just fine, telling me that the issue lies with my images.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Solved! The solution to this was a bit difficult as I did not attach the right xcassets folder to the Stackoverflow link. It turns out, I created a new "Watch OS App Icon" for my IOS target and so I was getting this error. This is a bit careless of me, as it is impossible to get a WatchOS Icon from running the IOS Target. Make sure you make an IOS App Icon for the IOS Target and a WatchOS App Icon for the WatchOS Target!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42690416/285594

Comment: @Ninja May I recommend that you post this as an answer to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watchkit AppIcon - The app icon set named "AppIcon" did not have any applicable content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335509/watchkit-appicon-the-app-icon-set-named-appicon-did-not-have-any-applicable)

Answer (score 26):

[image]

**You need follow the instructions in above image**

Answer (score 4):

make sure that you have a good size of AppIcon for example iPhone : 120 - 120 180 - 180