# Watchkit1: The app icon set did not have any applicable content

Tags: ios, watchkit, xcode7, watchos-2

I have an app + watch app1 developed on Xcode 6. It runs well and get submitted on Apple Store. In order to develop iOS 9 functions, I tested the app on Xcode 7.0.1 and something went wrong. The app cannot run at all and get the error: "Watchkit AppIcon - The app icon set named “WatchappIcon” did not have any applicable content " on Xcode 7.0.1 but run very well on Xcode 6.

[image: My watch1 app]

I've been checking other solutions that mentioned app icons are not complete. However, I've added all required app icons for iPhone app and Watch1 app when submitting to Apple Store. The app is alive on Apple Store.

Could someone tell me if you have the same issue and the give me some solutions. Thank you.

Comment: I've solved it on the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335509/watchkit-appicon-the-app-icon-set-named-appicon-did-not-have-any-applicable/32965850#32965850

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to make sure the images were assigned to the correct target. [image]